# MongoDB network access

Tags: node.js, mongodb

previously I didn't really understand networking. I want to still access the database with a different internet connection. I have added the mongodb atlas whitelist to my current ip or made it allow access from anywhere but I instead got an error. how do i finish this? thanks

this is my code to connect to the server

```
mongoose.connect(MONGODB_URI)
.then(result => {
    console.log('CONNECTED!');
    app.listen(3000);
})
.catch(err => console.log(err));
```

here this error message

> `D:\nodeJsApp\MyApp\node_modules\mongodb\lib\topologies\replset.js:368
>                 throw err;
>                 ^

Error: Error connecting to db: failed to connect to server `

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: D:\nodeJsApp\MyApp\node_modules\mongodb\lib\topologies\replset.js:368
              throw err;
              ^

Error: Error connecting to db: failed to connect to server

Comment: Please post the code you used that generates this error.

Comment: this is my code to connect to the server

    mongoose.connect(MONGODB_URI)
    .then(result => {
        console.log('CONNECTED!');
        app.listen(3000);
    })
    .catch(err => console.log(err));